# Indexing a table holding a mm relation

Tags: solr, typo3, extbase

I'm using a TYPO3 6.2.x instance along with lucene solr. The web-project contains a product catalog showing (who would have guessed?!) products and their possible components.

It's no problem to index the database table of the products or the components particular.

A third table holds the relation between these two tables by storing the specifix uid of the product and the component.

I've no idea how to index the relation. At the end I would like to search for a product and should get itself and furthermore the components of this product.

Perhaps somebody has had a similar prolem.

Comment: SOLR usually indexes *denormalized* documents, so you could build a new document for each product, which contains a product along with all its components (multivalued field). A component having relations to multiple products would of course be indexed multiple times. If this is not possible (an mm-relation could do that, but it depends), you could look into SOLRs join-capabilities. But I don't know anything about them, except for their existence.

Answer (score 1):

As Jost mentions in his comment, content of Solr is denormalized to the first norm. So you have to decide what entity you want to find. In your case this is answered: Product.

[image]
created with [DrawIO](https://www.draw.io)

So in Solr you would boil this down to a product with a list of components. A **schema** for this task would be rather simple, like the one shown below. This example is reduced to your problem, so you may need to extend it with additional fields and fieldTypes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="products" version="1.0">

  <types>
      <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
      <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField"  
        precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
      <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" 
        precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
  </types>


  <fields>
      <field name="id"         type="long"   indexed="true" stored="true" 
        multiValued="false" required="true" />
      <field name="name"       type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" 
        multiValued="false" />
      <field name="components" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" 
        multiValued="true"  />
      <field name="_version_"  type="long"   indexed="true"   stored="true" />
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```

As you can see it consists only of three relevant fields, the version field is for the Solr internal versioning and just needs to be present.

- **id** this is the UID of the product, as it is your leading entity and the one that shall be found in the results, it is required, unique and single-valued.
- **name** this is the name of your product, again as it is your leading entity and the one that shall be found in the results, it is unique and single-valued. If it should be unique or not is something I do not know.
- **components** this is a multivalued field. It will contain a list of the names of the components that belong to a product. And yes, this appears to be redundant, but this is the way Solr works.

---

Now we need to import data into this schema, as you wrote, you already have a dataimport in place. A **DIH config** for the schema above could look like this.

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="xxx" url="xxx" user="xxx" />
    <document name="product">
        <entity name="item" query="select * from product">

            <field column="ID" name="id" />
            <field column="NAME" name="name" />

            <entity name="component" query="select name as component_name from component, product_components where product_id='${item.ID}' and component.id = component_id">
                <field column="COMPONENT_NAME" name="components" />
            </entity>

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The mapping of the product should be straight forward, the only interesting fact is that the name of `product` is mapped to `item`. So that the columns of product are prefixed with `item` when being solr-internal. Like `where product_id='${item.ID}'`.

To flatten the many to many relationship a nested entity **component** is introduced. As you can see by the query, this one performs a join over the relation table to fetch all components that belong to one certain product. Then those components are mapped to the multivalued field components.

---

There is however one caveat with this solution. Solr's DIH will perform one query for every nested entity. This means that if you have 1.000 products DIH will perform one query to fetch all products plus 1.000 queries to fetch the components for every product. This is likely to produce a performance problem.

To tackle this there is **the [CachedSqlEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor)**, but as this is not the target of your question, I will not elaborate this here. There are several questions and blog articles about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your detailed answer, cheffe.

Meanwhile I´ve used another solution. I've created a mysql view that includes all of my wanted data, and indexed this view with solr.

```
SELECT
    concat(comp.uid, series.uid) As uid,
    comp.uid As cuid,
    comp.pid, comp.name, comp.teaser_text, comp.tstamp,comp.crdate, comp.cruser_id, comp.deleted, comp.hidden, comp.starttime, comp.endtime,
    comp.t3ver_oid, comp.t3ver_id, comp.t3ver_wsid, comp.t3ver_label, comp.t3ver_state, comp.t3ver_stage, comp.t3ver_count,
    comp.t3ver_tstamp, comp.t3ver_move_id, comp.sys_language_uid, comp.l10n_parent, comp.l10n_diffsource
FROM tx_productcatalog_domain_model_component As comp
    LEFT JOIN tx_productcatalog_series_component_mm As mm
        ON mm.uid_foreign = comp.uid
    LEFT JOIN tx_productcatalog_domain_model_series As series
        ON series.uid = mm.uid_local
```

Furthermore the common TYPO3 tx_solr extension needs a TCA for this view as if it were a domain model. It's enough to create a basic TCA entry in the "ext_tables.php" of the extension holding your data.

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_productcatalog_view_component');
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_productcatalog_view_component'] = array(
        'ctrl' => array(
                'sortby' => 'sorting',
                'title' => 'Component View',
                'label' => 'name',
                'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
                'crdate' => 'crdate',
                'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
                'dividers2tabs' => TRUE,

                'versioningWS' => 2,
                'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,

                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
                'delete' => 'deleted',
                'enablecolumns' => array(
                        'disabled' => 'hidden',
                        'starttime' => 'starttime',
                        'endtime' => 'endtime',
                ),
                'searchFields' => 'name, category, teaser_text, series_name',
                'iconfile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Public/Icons/haseke.gif'
        ),
);
```